# Excel VBA: Loop through Rows while separating date-span sequentially

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to find a method to loop through rows in a named table, copying each row over to another table and adding a value in a blank field on the end of each row which sequences the dates between a date span.

I came across code which can separate a date span successfully into rows, but have been having trouble creating a loop to go through each row of data and copying the rest over.

**Example of data from table (w/ headers):**

Table Name: **TblOGCalendar**
Sheet Name: **OGCalendarData**

[image: Example of raw calendar table data]

Should be copied over to look like the following:

Table Name: **TblR2Calendar**
Sheet Name: **R2CalendarData**

[image: Example of reformatted calendar table data]

This also has implications for another project that I am working on, in which they are wanting staff hours tracked and projected for Project work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you have so far, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***is is by no means an answer but more suited to help you learn stuff***

Loops through excel files can be done in various ways - some good and some bad. Just depends on your skill level & comfort level with working with code.

Im only going to outline 2 methods

**method #1** - Looping through the rows/columns themselves. I dont like this method as its bad practice - interacting with the applications objects is aperformance killer.

```
dim rng as range, rcell as range

' you have to tell the compiler where stuff is at
' this is important and a commmon mistake that causes quesitons her eon SO  

set rng = Thisworkbook.worksheets("Yoursheetname").Range("yourrange") 
for each rcell in rng.Cells
    'rcell is the current cell in the range you're looping through. 
    'Will physically loop through cells top to bottom, left to right
    ' do some processing.   
next rcell
```

**method #2** - Working in memory with arrays. This is the preferred method and the one you *should* get good at if you plan on using excel-vba more often in the future.

```
dim arr as variant ' you need this for dumping sheet to arrays
dim i as long, j as long 
arr = THisworkbook.Worksheets("yoursheet").UsedRange 
 ' there are many ways to get the desired range of a sheet - pick your favorite (after researching), and use that. 
' the ubound and lbound functions literally mean upper and lower. It basically says for i equal beginning of array dimension to last. 
' the number dictates what dimension of the array you want to loop through. Excel ranges are mutlidimensional by default. 1 = rows, 2 = columns
for i = LBound(arr,1) to UBound(arr,1) 
    for j = LBound(arr,2) to UBound(arr,2)
        ' do some processing
        ' array values can be accessed through this methods
        ' arr(i,j)
        ' arr(i, x) x being a number, like if you know i want column 7 of current iteration/row
        ' arr(i+1, j-1) plus values move down, or to the right (depending on dimension) while negative value go up or left (depending on dimension)
    next j
next i

'to put stuff back on your sheet after processing
thisworkbook.worksheets("yoursheet").range("yoursheet").value = arr
```

this should get you going on figuring things out for yourself